# Pyglet stops playing sounds after being called multiple times

Tags: python, macos, audio, mp3, pyglet

I have a large number of small mp3 files that I need to check individually.  In a python foreach file loop, I'm calling this function which uses pyglet:

```
def play(player,src):
  try:
    #music = pyglet.resource.media(src)
    music = pyglet.media.load(src, streaming=False)
    music.play()
    ans = raw_input("\tWas this sound good (r to replay, q to quit)? [y|n|r|q]: ")
    if (ans == 'r'): 
      return play(player,src)
    if (ans == 'q'):
      sys.exit(0)
    else:
      success = (ans == 'y')
  except pyglet.media.avbin.AVbinException, e:
    print "Exception playing file. Assuming bad."
    success = 0  
  print "%s -> %d" % ( src, success )
  return success
```

It works great for about 10 files but then it just stops working silently.  It acts like it is playing the sounds but there is just silence.  Is there some resource I should be unloading or deallocating or something?  I'm on OS X and initially had to install AVBin to get pyglet to work at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

First of all, you should take a look at the [player.queue](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.media.Player-class.html#queue) feature which offers a whole lot of automagic for stopping and releasing resources for your convenience.

Secondly if you get any errors, please do share!

Something along the lines of:

```
player = pyglet.media.Player()
player.queue(source1)
player.queue(source2)
player.play()
# wait 5 sec...
player.next()
```

If you prefer doing it the manual way between each playback, should help.

```
player.stop()
player.clear()
```